# How to escape all single and double quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have a variable in my script,

```
var st = ""
```

In that quotes I have to give a string and this string contains lot of single and double quotations.

I think there isn't any problem with single quotations, but a problem with the double quotes (") only.

In this I can't manually replace `\"` for all, even I tried with an editor that `"` replace with `\"`, but it's not working.

Comment: It is unclear what is asked here. Escaping `"` as `\"` within a string literal with `"` as delimiters is sufficient. If it does not work, you should ask a specific question with an example that actually demonstrates the issue. (“Not working” is not a description of what happens.)

Comment: Nowadays it's Backtick Quotes (at the time op asked the question backticks weren't part of JavaScript spec yet) Here's how it works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dr3y0ZT3vI

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You will need to use regular expression for this,

```
st.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

Check out more on regular expressions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Here is one mistake. not st.replace(). It should be str.replace().

Comment: the variable used in the qn is 'st'. Hence, st.replace()

Comment: @vasa minor point, this does not update 'st' in place, should use st = st.replace(/"/g, '\\"');

Comment: @blue-sky Agree, strings are immutable in JS.

Comment: This does not replace single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/["']/g, "")
```

Comment: This does not escape, it only removes all the quotes. This is not really what the OP was asking...but since you're doing the replace on the variable `str`, there's no fear about modifying original string ;-)